# Proving the squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, solution-verification

I know there are posts out there asking about this, but I didn't want to look at other solutions before I feel like I've solved it on my own or at least gotten close. If I'm on the wrong track, any hints would be very welcome instead of a solution. Here's what I have:

> Prove the suqeeze theorem: suppose $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $0<|x-c|<\delta$ for some $\delta > 0$. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} g(x) = L = \lim_{x\rightarrow c} h(x)$, then $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$.

Proof:
By definition, for $0 < |x-c| < \delta$, $\delta > 0 \implies |h(x)-L| < \epsilon$, $|g(x)-L| < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. Then,
$$ \begin{align}
|h(x) - g(x)| - |g(x) - L| &\leq |h(x) - g(x) + g(x) - L| && |h(x) - L| < \epsilon  \\
|h(x) - g(x)| - |g(x) - L| &< \epsilon && \text{limit definition}\\
|h(x) - g(x)| &\lt \epsilon + |g(x) - L| && \text{rearrange} \\
|h(x) - g(x)| &< 2\epsilon && \text{limit definition}
\end{align} $$

Now, since $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$, then $|g(x) - f(x)| \leq |h(x) - g(x)| $. This means that $|g(x) - f(x)| < 2\epsilon$. Then,
$$ \begin{align}
|f(x) - L| - |g(x) - f(x)| &\leq |g(x) - f(x) + f(x) - L|  && \text{triangle rule} \\
|f(x) - L| - |g(x) - f(x)| &< \epsilon && |g(x) - L | < \epsilon\\
|f(x) - L| &\lt \epsilon + |g(x)-f(x)| && \text{rearrange} \\
|f(x) - L| &< 3\epsilon && |g(x) - f(x) < 2\epsilon|
\end{align} $$

I could start with $\epsilon/3$ to end with $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$; regardless, is this proof correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof looks just about fine. Here is one comment I have:

> By definition, for $0 < |x-c| < \delta$, $\delta > 0 \implies |h(x)-L| < \epsilon$, $|g(x)-L| < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

It is unclear whether or not you are taking $\delta$ to be the minimum of the $\delta$'s coming from $h$ and $g$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Personally, I would make that more explicit if that is what you intended.

To shorten up the part where you show that $|h(x)-g(x)|<2\varepsilon$, I would make use of the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to c}h(x)=L=\lim\limits_{x\to c}g(x)$. Then $$|h(x)-g(x)|\leq |h(x)-L|+|L-g(x)|<2\varepsilon $$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0<|x-c|<\delta$ and $\varepsilon>0$.

Other than that the proof is correct.

Again, to cut down on some time, here is an alternate proof:

> Let $\varepsilon>0$. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0<|x-c|<\delta$, where $\delta$ is the minimum of the $\delta$'s coming from $g$ and $h$. Then we have
> \begin{align}-\varepsilon<-|g(x)-L|\leq g(x)-L\leq f(x)-L\leq h(x)-L\leq |h(x)-L|<\varepsilon\end{align}
> which implies $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes I get a fixed notion in my head but I wish I would've been more flexible and considered your approaches. Thanks for hiding the solution too btw, appreciate you letting me read it on my terms. Pretty nice proof, thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Your first sentence is not correct, though I understand what you mean. I think you should say something like: "Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. By making $\delta$ smaller if necessary, we may assume that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $$0 < |x - c| < \delta \implies |h(x) - L| < \epsilon \text{ and } |g(x) - L| < \varepsilon."$$

The rest of your math is correct, but you should preface the computations with something like "let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < |x - c| < \delta$ be arbitrary" because you never said what $x$ was.

The proofs of the inequalities seem a bit unnatural. In my opinion, it is more natural to do
\begin{align}
|h(x) - g(x)| &\leq |h(x) - L| + |L - g(x)| \\
&< 2\varepsilon.
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
|f(x) - L| &\leq |f(x) - g(x)| + |g(x) - L| \\
&\leq |h(x) - g(x)| + |g(x) - L| \\
&< 3\varepsilon.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I was definitely a bit sloppy, thanks for reminding me that I need to state things carefully. I also appreciate the comments on the inequalities, I guess I was thinking of them too rigidly in the form I knew, but of course moving them around the way you did makes them seem easier to recognize/parse